# A question about a detail in Walter Lewin's lecture on friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

The attached picture is a snapshot of lecture $8$ from the popular series of lectures given by Professor Walter Lewin at MIT. The subject matter is friction.

Assume we have known masses $m_1,m_2$ arranged as in the picture. Given that the mass $m_2$ is accelerating vertically downwards, so that $m_1$ is accelerating up the hill,
with some acceleration $a$. Assume that the kinetic coefficient of friction of the hill is known, say, $\mu_K$. The problem is to calculate $a$. Lewin's solution is as follows.
By Newton's second law, the component of the force acting on $m_1$ in the $x$-direction (see picture) must then satisfy the equation:
$$T-m_1g\sin\alpha-\mu_Km_1g\cos\alpha = m_1a$$
This is an equation in two unknowns, the acceleration $a$, and the tension $T$ in the string. Next, Lewin argues that since $m_2$ is also accelerating in the same acceleration $a$, we must have a second equation, for the component of the force acting on $m_2$ in the vertical direction:
$$m_2g-T=m_2a$$
and now it is a trivial matter to solve two equations in two unknowns. One may follow his argument in the video [Lewin's lecture on friction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWh-enOdXM4), starting at time $23:10$.

My question is this: Why is it possible to assume that the masses $m_1,m_2$ are accelerating in the same magnitude? How is it possible to apply Newton's second law to two different masses, each moving in a completely different direction, with the same magnitude of acceleration? A naive answer could be: "well, Lewin said that the whole system is accelerating with magnitude $a$, so both masses, being part of the same system, must accelerate in the same magnitude". But I cannot convince myself with this answer, because the masses are not moving in the same direction, so it makes no sense to speak of a single acceleration common to both of them, or does it?

[image: Lewin Mechanics Lecture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here I think is that the string is assumed to be rigid, that is the end points of any two parts of the string need to keep the same distance or in other words move at the same rate. But that means one end has to be moving at the same rate as m1 and the other end has to move at the same rate as m2 which by transitivity means m1 and m2 move at the same rate.

[image: both ends of the colored cut of the string must move with the same speed at all times]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Without such an assumption the word "acceleration" seems to make no sense in this context.